# The text font size of content in editor is not matching with the text font size in corresponding pdf report

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, wicked-pdf

I am using tinymce editor for writing the content and going to generate pdf report for it and when text font size in editor is compared with font size of pdf report, the font size becomes smaller in pdf report compared to text font size in tiny mce editor when the corresponding pdf is generated. I am rendering pdf in the following way.

`render :pdf => "#{report.name}",
        :orientation => paper_orientation.nil? ? 'Portrait' : paper_orientation,
        :page_height => @page_height.nil? ? '27.94cm' : @page_height+"cm",
        :page_width => @page_width.nil? ? '21.59cm' : @page_width+"cm",

:margin => paper_orientation == 'Portrait' ? paper_margin.nil? ? {:top => '2.1cm',:bottom => '2.5cm', :left => '2cm',:right => '2.1cm'} : {:top => (paper_margin[:top].to_f+ 2.1).to_s + "cm",:bottom => paper_margin[:bottom]+"cm", :left => paper_margin[:left]+"cm",:right => (paper_margin[:right].to_f + 0.1).to_s + "cm" } :

paper_margin.nil? ? {:top => '2.8cm',:bottom => '2.5cm', :left => '2cm',:right => '2.2cm'} : {:top => (paper_margin[:top].to_f+ 2.8).to_s + "cm",:bottom => paper_margin[:bottom]+"cm", :left => paper_margin[:left]+"cm",:right => (paper_margin[:right].to_f + 0.2).to_s + "cm" },
:footer => {}`
can anyone please help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably a print stylesheet overriding or replacing the one used on the page.  How are you rendering the pdf?  How does it look if you do print preview in your browser - is it the same as the pdf?

Comment: What's with all the nested terniary statements? Your issue comes down to CSS styling (in all your questions tagged wicked-pdf thus far). Make sure you are including all necessary stylesheets, and include your own with `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag`. Then use `:debug => true` to tweak it until you are happy, then preview as pdf to make sure.